# Failed to install fcgi gem

Tags: ruby, apache, fastcgi, redmine

Windows Server 2016, Apache 2.4, Ruby 3.0.6 (with webkit), Rails 7.0.4.3

I'm trying to install FCGI gem with the command `gem install fcgi` but it returns that error:

```
C:\Apache24\htdocs\redmine-5.0.5>gem install fcgi
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing fcgi:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/fcgi-0.9.2.2/ext/fcgi
C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for fcgiapp.h... no
checking for fastcgi/fcgiapp.h... no

current directory: C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/fcgi-0.9.2.2/ext/fcgi
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20230518-6868-obubmv sitelibdir\=./.gem.20230518-6868-obubmv clean
make: *** No hay ninguna regla para construir el objetivo 'clean'.  Alto.

current directory: C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/fcgi-0.9.2.2/ext/fcgi
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20230518-6868-obubmv sitelibdir\=./.gem.20230518-6868-obubmv
make: *** No hay objetivos.  Alto.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/fcgi-0.9.2.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/3.0.0/fcgi-0.9.2.2/gem_make.out
```

It seems that the library fcgiapp.h is missing.

I have tried to install diferents fcgi versions, with the same result.

Also, I'm tried tu put the archive fcgiapp.h on the file: C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/fcgi-0.9.2.2/ext/fcgi
With no result.